# What would a default xorg.conf look like?

Tags: xorg

I'm trying to setup `Xdmx`, which isn't easy. I'm having issues with `xinerama` and differing colour depths, which can be rectified by change `xorg.conf` on each of the machines. Of course, these days `xorg.conf` doesn't exist because the drivers do all the hard work for us.

So, what should a default `xorg.conf` look like?

Comment: This is a bit of a generic Xorg question. Possibly better suited to SuperUser.

Comment: I disagree, the Pi is a specific setup.

Comment: Nah, the xorg on the Pi wont look any different to any other system for Xdmx.

Comment: Course it will - xorg.conf is specific to the RPi - it tells the local Xserverhow to start.

Comment: Let us talk about this in chat later. I'm quite sure it isn't Pi specific.

Comment: I have never once in all my days seen Xinerama actually working. It's a sad, sad story, but I just haven't come across a system that used it and not had some sort of display problem. No matter how hard I've tried, it simply doesn't seem to like me.

Comment: @AndrewLarsson I've got Xinerama working on my desktop now!

Comment: @AlexChamberlain I'm jealous. On my systems that have more than one monitor, I'm stuck starting a separate window manager (not window system) on each. The NVIDIA graphics cards/drivers have their own version of Xinerama called TwinView, though. It works great as long as you only have NVIDIA cards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've added `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-monitors.conf`, which seems to output the same logs as before, but allows customisation. I had problems with setting 24-bit depth though.

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier "main"
    Driver     "fbdev"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier "Monitor0"
    Option "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "Screen0"
    Device     "main"
    Monitor    "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth 16
    SubSection "Display"
            Depth 16
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

Comment: I also had trouble with depth and HDMI. Use `config.txt` to set the HDMI output.

Comment: I love you Alex, for replying to your own post with what worked.