# High DPI @ lxde

Tags: xorg, lxde

The touchscreen monitor I'm using for my Raspberry Pi is about 150 DPI (1280x800 @ 10"). Such high dpi is hard to work with with a touch interface. I'd like to increase the DPI such that text is rendered larger and that the QT UI I'm programming will use larger buttons (etc).

I've tried a couple things, including using `xrandr --dpi` and adding `Xft.dpi: 150` to `~/.Xdefaults`. Neither of these things have made a difference.

I'm using the default LXDE window manager.

What do I need to do to increase the DPI?

*Edit:* solution is to use ~/.Xresources instead of ~/.Xdefaults. A symlink solves this easily enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look in ~/.Xresources for

```
! Xft settings ---------------------------------------------------------------
Xft.dpi: 96
Xft.antialias: true
Xft.rgba: rgb
Xft.hinting: true
Xft.hintstyle: hintslight
```

If you change any of these you will have to log out and log back in for changes to take effect

Do you have an xorg.conf file in /etc/X11? You could try creating one, that should work if all else is failing.

Comment: It's looking for .Xresources, not .Xdefaults. So I ln -s ~/.Xdefaults ~/.Xresources and it works :)

Comment: See http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/948/86 for a default xorg.conf.